# How to customise Kendo ui for jquery for integrating to angular

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

When i install kendo ui for jquery in angular application as mentioned here..
http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/kendo-jquery/

and after importing

**import '@progress/kendo-ui';**

vendor.bundle.js shown around **3 MB** size..

Is there any customisation  option  for **kendo ui for jquery** components to use in angular project?

I have to use the kendo ui for jquery components which are not implemented in kendo ui for angular version.

Answer (score 0):

We can import the required kendo ui for jquery components only as shown below.

import '@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.datetimepicker';

import '@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.window';